# sphinx-apidoc to not include root directory in path

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Suppose I have a folder structure

```
A\__init__.py
A\math\__init__.py
A\math\others.py
A\stats\__init__.py
A\stats\andthese.py
```

I have `A` in my python path, so normally I do `import math.others`, but `import A.math.others` will fail.

Now in folder `A`, I do

```
sphinx-apidoc -o ./documentation ./ --full --force
```

to generate the configuration files, eg

```
A\documentation\A.rst
A\documentation\A.math.rst
A\documentation\A.math.others.rst
```

Then in `A\documentation` I do `make html`. This will fail because it cannot import `A.math.others` (I don't want to make A's parent folder a python path.)

How can I make `sphinx-apidoc` to generate config files without the root directory included in the import path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

In the generated `A\documentation\conf.py`, uncomment the lines 18-20

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, u'D:/A')
```

And modify the last line to

```
sys.path.insert(0, u'D:')
```

Now all imports will work.